# Prevent root in appspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I set up CodeDeploy with Bitbucket UI. So if I'm sharing my repo with someone he can deploy to the server. And he can also modify `appspec.yml` file, what means that he could add `hooks` and run them as `root` user.

I know that this is unlikely could be happened but I don't want to give root access for all contributors.

Can I prevent hooks from `runas: root` somehow? Maybe I can add some restrictions for IAM role?

Comment: 1) If you use `CodeCommit` for your git repo and use `CodeDeploy` using `CodePipelines`, then you can add step in pipeline to manual approve before any deployment, not sure about the same in Bitbucket repo and Bitbucket pipelines.

Comment: 2) Another option is to keep a seperate branch for `dev` and add `ignore merge` for file `appspecs.yml`, this will never merge the changes made by dev in `appspecs.yml`.